# ATcommand at+cops? gives undefined return

Tags: at-command

I'm working with the EGS5 Cinterion wireless module. 
I located the module in an area where I recieve just a few operators with low signal strength (-100dBm - -105dBm). When I use `AT+COPS=?` I see that 4 operators are available.

`AT+COPS=? +COPS: (1,"E-Plus",,"26203"),(1,"Telekom.de",,"26201"), 
(1,"Vodafone.de",,"26202"),(1,"o2 - de",,"26207"),,(0-4),(0,2)`

`AT+CREG? +CREG: 0,0`
and `AT+COPS? +COPS: 1`

Changing to one of the operators above with `AT+COPS=1,2,......`returns `OK`, but when i check `AT+COPS?`I get `+COPS: 1`again.

Changing to `AT+COPS=0`returns `ERROR`

I don't understand why I can't connect to a network, even it is available. My SIM isn't locked or anything, and all is working perfectly when I put the wireless module in an area with better reception

EDIT: 
`at^smond`returns
`^SMOND:262,07,C762,C389,76,687,109,,,0,,,2,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,0,2,2,99`
so im connected to PLMN 26207, thats correct? But `AT+COPS?`returns still `+COPS: 1`

Comment: I have no idea where this belongs, but it's not here.

Comment: OK, can anyone tell me where to ask?

Comment: This is the right place to ask such questions.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are confused about what `AT+COPS?` returns. The first number does not correspond to which network the phone is attached to, it is the `<mode>` value.

The command is defined in [27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm), and its syntax is

```
Table 36: +COPS parameter command syntax
Command                   Possible response(s)

+COPS=[<mode>[,<format>   +CME ERROR: <err>
[,<oper>[,<AcT>]]]]

+COPS?                    +COPS: <mode>[,<format>,<oper>[,<AcT>]]
                          +CME ERROR: <err>

+COPS=?                   +COPS: [list of supported (<stat>,long alphanumeric
                          <oper>,short alphanumeric <oper>,numeric <oper>
                          [,<AcT>])s][,,(list of supported <mode>s),(list of
                          supported <format>s)]
                          +CME ERROR: <err>
```

and `<mode>` is defined as

```
<mode>:
0 automatic (<oper> field is ignored)
1 manual (<oper> field shall be present, and <AcT> optionally)
2 deregister from network
3 set only <format> (for read command +COPS?), do not attempt registration/deregistration (<oper> and
<AcT> fields are ignored); this value is not applicable in read command response
4 manual/automatic (<oper> field shall be present); if manual selection fails, automatic mode (<mode>=0) is
entered
```

So the response `+COPS: 1` only tells you that the phone is attached to
a specific network operator. The `AT+COPS?` command could have given the details of which operator, but those parameters are optional so the phone is not required to.

Why mode value 0 fails I cannot say, but it might be that the module only supports automatic under some conditions and not always (say for some `AcT` values). And regarding switching operator, notice that this is dependent on roaming agreements with your home network operator and each of the guest networks. So just because `AT+COPS=?` returns a list of N operators, that does not imply that you are allowed to switch to any of them.